# What gets deleted when I delete a model in django (postgress)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Lets say I have a model Books:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    author = models.Charfield()
```

and later I set up another model called BookReviews which links to Books:

```
class BookReviews(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
    content = models.TextField()
```

But I messed up and I want to delete model BookReviews completely. When I run

> python manage.py migrate

I get a warning message:

> Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
>   be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?

Does that mean any entries linked to in Books will also be deleted even if those entries existed before BookReviews?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wonder about `on_delete` option in `ForeignKey`

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django will emulate the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the on_delete argument. For example, if you have a nullable ForeignKey and you want it to be set null when the referenced object is deleted:

When deleting your `Books` object, all foreign `BookReviews` objects deleted because `on_delete=models.CASCADE` is default. your model is same as below

```
    class Books(models.Model):
            name = models.Charfield()
            author = models.Charfield()

    class BookReviews(models.Model):
            book = models.ForeignKey(
                    Books,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            )
            content = models.TextField()
```

If you don't want automatically delete `BookReviews`, you can use other `on_delete` options, like this

```
    class BookReviews(models.Model):
            book = models.ForeignKey(
                    Books,
                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                    blank=True,
                    null=True,
            )
```

There's many useful example in django documentation, so check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for more information.

> P.S. after django 2.0 version, you should write `on_delete` option when writing FroeignKey field.